# Using LiveServer on port 8080

Tags: angular, port, npm-live-server

I'm currently working through the Angular 2 QuickStart instructions at https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html and have run into a problem running LiveServer. When I start LiveServer as per the instructions, I get an error in my brower:

```
Error Code: 502 Proxy Error
```

I've realised with a bit of investigation that my proxy is using port 8080 and so is LiveServer. If I turn my proxy off, then I can see the angular site in my browser.

So, my question is, what is the best port to change LiveServer to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in the live-server README file (which I probably should have read before posting the question) which says:

If a file `~/.live-server.json` exists it will be loaded and used as default options for live-server on the command line

So, for the benefit of anyone else who needs to do this, I've created a .liver-server.json file and set the port to 8081 like this:

```
{"port": 8181, 
"host": "0.0.0.0", 
"open": false, 
"root":"/Users/abc/Projects/angular2-quickstart",
"ignore": "",
"file": "index.html",
"wait": 1000 }
```

This has worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` file add the default port for your application

`"scripts": {  "start": "live-server --port=8082", },`